Does a thread lingering within an instance member method keep the instance alive if all other references are dropped?
Pretty simple yes/no question:
Hypothetically, I have a class with an instance member method.  Say the method sleeps the thread for an hour.
I assign the instance member method to be run by ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(InstanceMethod).  Then I get rid of all other references to the instance.
Will the ThreadPool thread keep the instance alive or will it wake up and try to work in a destroyed/GCed class object instance?

Aren't ThreadPools a derivative of CustomThreadPools from the old days? If that is the case then that one thread that spawned would continue to run, there is no cancelation. :/

https://cbrumme.dev/lifetime

You can  always assume (unless you're doing something really evil and unsafe) that the runtime will never let anything access a (managed) object which has been deallocated

Why do you want to know? The instance must remain "alive" as long as any thread could use it. Instance methods typically use or update fields of the instances on which they are invoked, but there's no requirement that an instance method do either of those things. This feels like a question about an implementation detail (see my "Answer" below, and the comments on my "Answer") rather than a question about the C# language. But maybe I'm  not seeing it the way you see it. Again, why do you want to know?

@SolomonSlow I'm making a "poll thread" class that can be stopped and restarted, since it sleeps the thread to create a "tick," I have the finalizer telling the current thread to exit its poll loop and return to the thread pool but maybe that's another problem the finalizer won't run while the thread is sitting in the "tick" method and it must be manually stopped first?  I was actually kinda hoping losing reference to the object would stop the poll thread but allow it to safely wake up.

I deleted my answer. It's inconceivable to me that somebody would intentionally allow the GC to reclaim an instance while there was any possibility that the program still needed the instance for any reason whatsoever. But, comments on my now-deleted answer made me realize that I don't know everything there is to know about C# garbage collection and how it interacts with multiple threads.

Assuming release build with tiered compilation turned off, it will mostly depend on whether there are instance or instance member accesses in the method body after the point where Thread.Sleep was called.
This is confirmed by this passage from the .NET Memory Analysis Document by the main maintainer of the GC Maoni Stephens:

Stack variables, especially for C# programs, are actually not talked
about very much. The reason is that JIT also does a good job realizing
when a stack variable is no longer in use. When a method is done, a
stack root is guaranteed to disappear. But even before that, JIT can
also figure out when a stack var isn't needed anymore so will not
report to GC, even when a GC happens in the middle of a method. Note
that it is not the case in DEBUG builds.

Even though this doesn't seem like a stack variable we have ourselves declared, it is implicitly there on the stack - see this answer. So the above quote still applies in our case.
Example code to illustrate this makes use of the WeakReference type which according to the docs:

Represents a weak reference, which references an object while still
allowing that object to be reclaimed by garbage collection.

class Foo {
    int bar = 42;
    public void InstanceMethod(object o) {
        var wr = new WeakReference(this);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive); // False if below is commented / True otherwise
        // Console.WriteLine(this.bar); //will keep the instance alive
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
var dedicatedThread = new Thread(foo.InstanceMethod);
dedicatedThread.Start();
dedicatedThread.Join(); // False

var lambdaThread = new Thread(() => {
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.InstanceMethod(null);
});
lambdaThread.Start();
lambdaThread.Join(); // False

foo = new Foo();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(foo.InstanceMethod));
// False
Thread.Sleep(3000);// Console.ReadLine

I've included multiple versions of offloading the instance method work to another thread - via lambda / and as a WaitCallback delegate instance - the results are the same.
This shows that as Jeremy Lakeman commented the behavior that we notice for our class also applies to that of a delegate that holds the reference to our object and its instance method. That is when we do :
delegate.Invoke();

if the delegate isn't used in the method that contains the code above does not need the delegate, it will be GCed and won't hold our object alive by itself too.

The delegate instance would keep this alive, if the delegate was also live. But as you've noticed, release builds will shrink the lifetime of local variables, so they will go out of scope when they are last referenced. This is to minimise the number of used CPU registers and allocated stack space.

@JeremyLakeman yes, good point. My remark was more influenced by something in the ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem source code where the delegate lived as a field of another object. I thought this might be problematic. Didn't want to get into all the queueing logic.

this is the class that gets the WaitCallback as a field

That is an utterly unintuitive answer.  Crazy that it depends on compile time optimization.  I also feel totally unqualified to accept the answer at this time cause it's just so surprising.  Are the //false comments in your other thread methods meant to indicate "wr.IsAlive" in "InstanceMethod(object obj)" is false?

The rule is that objects can be collected as soon as nothing else is going to access them. Variable scope is irrelevant: what matters is whether anything will access that variable again. This includes the this reference: that's just another variable to the runtime. In Debug, variable lifetimes are artificially extended to match scope to give a better debugging experience (so you can always inspect a variable that's in scope)

(Note that disabling tiered compilation shouldn't matter here, I think?)

@ThisHandleNotInUse What do you find unintuitive about this? GC has recognized that the instance will never be used again, why shouldn't it collect it? Put it this way: without using a WeakReference, the effect is not observable and will make no difference to the code.

@ThisHandleNotInUse the WeakReference instance is an object that has a reference to an object but this reference is not keeping the object alive like normal references would. As such it can be used to see if the object has no other references but the one it is holding (IsAlive=false). If you want to dabble a bit more so things like this won't feel unintuitive - I recommend this youtube series and the book by the series' author which is due for a second edition.

@Charlieface  I'm just always in awe at how "perfect" C# and C++ compilers and APIs are like seeing a wonder of the world.  So I find it fascinating that the "stack variables" (are they stack variables in C#? I'm a bit rusty cause I'm a hobbiest and I haven't been programming much until recently) will pass out of scope before the end of scope "on a release build."  EDIT: "local variables" I guess.


Will the ThreadPool thread keep the instance alive or will it wake up and try to work in a destroyed/GCed class object instance?

Yes, the ThreadPool will keep the instance alive. In order to be able to invoke its method, the ThreadPool holds a reference to the instance until the method is invoked. The method will be invoked pretty quickly, normally instantaneously, not after an hour. After the ThreadPool invokes the method, it no longer holds a reference to the instance. But all the code in the method will run, and all the objects needed by the code will be kept alive at least as long as they are needed.
There is a case that the code will not run to the end, which is the premature termination of the process (ThreadPool threads are background threads, and so they don't prevent a process from terminating).

Your answer is great and right to the point but I'm accepting the other answer because it highlights a particular nuance.
